# How to access outlook using pywin32 when outlook is closed

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook, pywin32, office-automation

I am trying to reply to outlook mails using com then move it to another folder. It works fine when the outlook is open but when it is closed I get all sorts of errors , even though I used the "outlook = win.Dispatch('Outlook.application').GetNamespace('MAPI')" command

Below are the error lines I got when I tried to 1) Access the subject of the mail 2)Move a mail to other folder.

```
com_error: (-2147023170, 'The remote procedure call failed.', None, None) #1
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'The operation failed.', None, 0, -2147467259), None)#2
```

Can anyone please tell me how to access , reply as well as move mails when outlook is not open?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook is a singleton which means you can't run two instances of the application at the same time. Even if you create a new Outlook `Application` instance by using the following line of code:

```
outlook = win.Dispatch('Outlook.application').GetNamespace('MAPI')
```

The existing application instance will be used, i.e. you will be connected to the running application.

So, if the user closes Outlook at some point your objects may become invalid and you may get exceptions in the code like that.

Comment: Oh thanks for your reply . How can I overcome this problem? I want to run the program when outlook is open , closed or closed in between . Also the code works at times and throws such error the rest of the times . Could you please tell if there is any other way I can automate outlook replies , I basically want to run a python program taking the mail body as input and reply to the mail back with the output of program .Cannot use power automate as it is not free for such tasks. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can set up rules in Outlook, so the email will be replied automatically. Also you may consider creating a VBA macro where you could programmatically do whatever you need.

Comment: In case of Exchange profiles you may consider using [EWS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/start-using-web-services-in-exchange) or Graph API (for Office365).

Comment: Oh okay thanks. The issue is I'm not closing outlook in between the program ,  I'm able to connect to outlook but after a while it gets disconnected and get the Rpc sever not available error .

Comment: Also , to run VBA code, "run a script" option isn't available. Any help on that?

Comment: I'd suggest posting new questions in new threads, so readers could recognize questions and answers easily.